# button transparent in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, button, transparency, alpha

is it possible in visual studio 2010 (in a Windows Forms application) to change the alpha button to make it almost transparent?

Comment: You say 'Windows Forms' - is that specifically WinForms and not WPF?  (WPF allows control transparency)

Comment: not WPF, what can I do to control trasparency in a button?

Answer (score 1):

setting form's alpha will effect whole form and its contents. if u want particular control to be transperent try use png image with alpha channel. this technic works in vista and newer windows.

for XP u need to do pinvoke graphic32.dll(not sure about dll name) to build custom gdi.